# How to know if child views are rendered in a region

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on an application that uses Backbone marionette. I have a layout containing regions which in turn contains child regions. In the onRender function of the parent region, the child regions are rendered by calling 'showChildView' function. I would like to set tab indexes after the child regions are rendered. Is there a way to know if my child regions are rendered?

I tried using onShow/onAttach on parent region's view. But no luck!

Comment: just trigger a custom event from the child view's render method..?

Comment: Thanks!  But I'm having multiple child views, I need a way to handle events from all of them

Comment: You can trigger the same event from all of them and have the parent view listen to all of them...?!

Comment: Yes, I'd have to maintain the list of all child views somewhere in my parent view and listen to all of them, and set tab indexes when I've received the event from all of them. Just wanted to know if there is any simpler way of doing this

Comment: You probably wouldn't have to keep a list of names, rather, count the number of regions on your view Object.keys(this.regions).length, and each childview's trigger will increment a counter until you know they are all rendered.

Answer (score 1):

to check if the region "myRegion" is currently showing a view try

```
var childView = parentView.getRegion('myRegion').currentView;
```

then you can check if the view has been already rendered

```
if (childView && childView.isRendered) { ...
```

In your case, after the call of "showChildView" your child views should be rendered, aren't they?

Comment: Thanks! But my child views are rendered asynchronously. When do I check if they are rendered. If I choose to have this check, I need to know for sure that they are rendered and I don't have a way to do that, unless some event is triggered from the child view. But I'm having multiple child views, I need a way to handle events from all of them

Comment: with asynchronous rendering you could use the _attach_ event adding a listener for each child view: `_.each([...child views...], function(view){this.listenToOnce(view, 'attach', function(){/* Increment counter and do something when the counter reach child views number */});}, this)`.      With JS6 you could also use promises creating a promise for each view render method and then calling [Promise.all](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.all) from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome dev tools you can check if the dom element for the region is showing up in the source code. If yes then your region is rendered.

Alternatively, you can also debug by adding a onRender() method in the child view and adding a console.log() statement inside it.